# Why is calc not defined at onclick event attribute?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am a new aspiring developer and these things are new to me. Can you help?

when I try to run my code I get an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: calc is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick".

I want the answer to show up inside the div with the id "result" but it's not working.

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
            Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
            Operator: 
                <select id="operator">
                    <option value="add">Add</option>
                    <option value="sub">Subtract</option>
                    <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
                    <option value="div">Divide</option>
                </select>
                <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>


enter code here
```

JS code:

```
function calc() {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
    var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
    var calculate;

    if (op == "add") {
        calculate = a + b;
    } else if (op == "sub") {
        calculate = a - b;
    } else if (op == "mul") {
        calculate = a * b;
    } else if (op == "div") {
        calculate = a / b;
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", calc);
}
```

Comment: Because you forgot the `<script>` element

Comment: Unrelated, but you'd adding an event listener in the event listener code itself; that's likely not what you're intending. How are you including the function in your HTML?

Comment: (Recursively adding a click listener inside the click listener is a mistake too, but not the cause of your problem as far as I can tell)

Comment: I changed my code... the event listener as you guys call it. I'm not sure if this is still called an event listener but this is what I followed on the tutorial, it worked for him but it's still not working for me.

document.querySelector("result").innerHTML = calculate;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work in this code pen I created: https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/eYJRXMp?editors=1111

you don't need to add an event listener inside the function, the onclick attribute is the event listener.

edit: as another user pointed out, it's missing the script tag

```
<script src="./filename.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is you are adding an event listener to an event already "listened"
The good way to write it would be

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calc() {
        var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
        var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
        var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
        var calculate;

        if (op == "add") {
            calculate = a + b;
        } else if (op == "sub") {
            calculate = a - b;
        } else if (op == "mul") {
            calculate = a * b;
        } else if (op == "div") {
            calculate = a / b;
        }
    }
</script>
```

After that you can change the end of the function to output the result into your html like this :

```js
    document.querySelector('#result').innerText = calculate;
```

Intentionnaly I didn't show you where to put it, to make you work a little, to train that little developer brain you'll need to have to be a good developer ;)